# Shorten verbose CSS that repeats combinations of elements and pseudo-classes

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

I am adding different pseudo-classes and elements to the same few parts of my table. Is there a way to save work and effort by summing them up somehow? I am not sure how to do it.

```css
.tr1 th:nth-child(1) {background-color: green;}
.tr1 th:nth-child(5) {background-color: green;}
.tr2 td:nth-child(2) {background-color: green;}
.tr2 td:nth-child(4) {background-color: green;}
.tr3 td:nth-child(3) {background-color: green;}
.tr4 td:nth-child(4) {background-color: green;}
.tr4 td:nth-child(2) {background-color: green;}

.tr1 th:nth-child(1):hover {background-color: hotpink;}
.tr1 th:nth-child(5):hover {background-color: hotpink;}
.tr2 td:nth-child(2):hover {background-color: hotpink;}
.tr2 td:nth-child(4):hover {background-color: hotpink;}
.tr3 td:nth-child(3):hover {background-color: hotpink;}
.tr4 td:nth-child(4):hover {background-color: hotpink;}
.tr4 td:nth-child(2):hover {background-color: hotpink;}

.tr1 th:nth-child(1)::selection {color: hotpink;}
.tr1 th:nth-child(5)::selection {color: hotpink;}
.tr2 td:nth-child(2)::selection {color: hotpink;}
.tr2 td:nth-child(4)::selection {color: hotpink;}
.tr3 td:nth-child(3)::selection {color: hotpink;}
.tr4 td:nth-child(4)::selection {color: hotpink;}
.tr4 td:nth-child(2)::selection {color: hotpink;}
```

Comment: See if SCSS will do what you need. It has a `&` that means "repeat the previous selector" and you can add a pseudo-element selector after it, as shown here: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#using-the-with-pseudo-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the selectors using [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) and comma `,`

```css
.tr1 th:is(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(5)),
:is(.tr2,.tr4) td:is(:nth-child(2),:nth-child(4)),
.tr3 td:nth-child(3) {background-color:green}

.tr1 th:is(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(5)):hover,
:is(.tr2,.tr4) td:is(:nth-child(2),:nth-child(4)):hover,
.tr3 td:nth-child(3):hover {background-color:hotpink}

.tr1 th:is(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(5))::selection,
:is(.tr2,.tr4) td:is(:nth-child(2),:nth-child(4))::selection,
.tr3 td:nth-child(3)::selection {color:hotpink}
```